# Java servlet for writing excel file causes error in IE7/IE8

Tags: java, excel, internet-explorer, servlets, download

I have a jsf app and when the user clicks a button, there is a backing bean method which calls this servlet.

The problem is that in IE7 and IE8, the file is unable to be downloaded. It gives the error message:

`Internet Explorer cannot download ExcelGenerator from mydomain.com`

What do i need to do to get this to work in IE7/IE8? Do i need to set some additional headers?

Backing bean method which calls servlet:

```
public void generateExcel()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String url = context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/ExcelGenerator";
    context.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
}
```

Servlet that generates the excel file:

```
 public class ExcelGenerator extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelGenerator.class);

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            super.init(config);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Results");
            List<List<TableData>> results = (List<List<TableData>>) request.getSession().getAttribute("results");
            String tableName = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("tableName");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date date = new Date();
            String filename = tableName+"-"+df.format(date)+".xlsx";
            OutputStream out = null;

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);

            int rowCounter = 0;

            // Create the rows
            for(List<TableData> l : results) {

                int counter = 0;
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);

                for(TableData td : l) {

                    Cell cell = row.createCell(counter);

                    // if we're on the first row, get the column description, else get the data
                    if(rowCounter == 0) {
                        cell.setCellValue(td.getColumnDescription());
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(td.getData());
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                rowCounter++;
            }

            try {
                out = response.getOutputStream();
                wb.write(out);
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.debug(e.getStackTrace().toString());
            } finally {
                out.close();
                wb.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Internet Explorer cannot download ExcelGenerator from mydomain.

This error is typical when the domain is on HTTPS and the response doesn't allow caching. See also [MS KB 316431](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431).

The fix is rather simple:

```
if (request.isSecure()) {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
}
```

#### See also:

- [IE cannot download foo.jsf. IE was not able to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034454/internet-explorer-cannot-download-the-file-served-by-jsf/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/) which lists compatibility of recent browser versions with the `Content-Disposition` header. There are certain combinations of values, especially around how you encode the filename part, that can cause IE to display an error.

Answer (score 0):

**I have faced this issue and following entry resolve this problem**

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-xls; charset=utf-8");

response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+filename);

response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3800");